# AWS ApiGateway Execution failed due to configuration error: Unable to transform response

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, httpresponse

I am trying to implement Lambda Integration with Aws ApiGateway that i can able to parse input with my request mapping template but i can not return a proper json object with response mapping template script. It gets every time "Execution failed due to configuration error: Unable to transform response" that i checked the api gateway logs and api gateway return 500 error

lambda returns this message

```
{
"statusCode": 200,
"body": "{\"name\":\"dummy\",\"surname\":\"dummy\"}"}
```

But i with response mapping template i am trying to return

```
{"name":"dummy","surname":"dummy"}
```

my response mapping vtl script is like that without assigning it to somewhere

```
$util.parseJson($input.json('$'))
```

and also tried

```
$util.parseJson($input.json('$.body'))
```

Comment: Did you got any success with this, I am getting the same issue?